# Http PUT request: What's the basic syntax?

Tags: http, rest, tcp, localhost, put

In a Max/MSP module I have a simple Tcp client that sends data to a server. I want to use this to send a PUT request to my MIDI/OSC controller(an Eigenharp). It asks for the PUT request to make one of its lights turn on.

Now, the following works in cURL:

```
curl http://localhost:1024/column/1/row/5 -X PUT --data green
```

However,

How can I accomplish something like that using a basic TCP stream, without any extra libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a generic way to figure it out (which is, so to speak, a trowel instead of fish):

First,

```
> nc -l -p 7070
```

which will begin listening to the tcp port 7070. Then (from a separate shell)

```
> curl http://localhost:7070/column/1/row/5 -X PUT --data green
```

After that `nc` will print something like:

```
PUT /column/1/row/5 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: (Some curl info here)
Host: localhost:7070
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

green
```

Which is more or less what you need to send through the socket.

You can use the very same `nc` ([netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)) utility as a network Swiss-army knife as well to send the data:

```
> cat request.txt | nc host port
```

That said, [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is your best friend.